# How to copy a function into multiple cells with only specifc variables changing? EXCEL

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, editing

I'm tracking my spent time on specific things like reading and watching in excel.

If i log something for watching, the cell changes to a formula that adds the time spent based on the episodes I watched, which i have to log into different cell. The medium can be selected in a drop down menu.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Format | Time | Episode |
| 2 | Anime |  | 1 |

Following table set variable for each episode time
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjEm1.png)

Now I determine a function that looks at format and decides if there is anime or something different selected. If anime is selected in the dropdown menu, in the adjacent cell episode, should have this formula.

`=IF(B2="Anime"; IF(D2="1"; H2; IF(D2="2"; H3; IF(D2="3"; H4; and so on)`

This works on my end, but the problem i want to fix is, how do i apply this for cells A2:A1000?
If I just copy cell C2 with the function down, the selected table is messed up, meaning moved one down, because i copied the cell one down.

What I want IF copying the cell down
`=IF(B3="Anime"; IF(D2="1"; H2; IF(D2="2"; H3; IF(D2="3"; H4; and so on)`
Notice only the B2 changing to B3

But what excel does
`=if(B2="Anime"; IF(D2="1"; H3; IF(D2="2"; H4; IF(D2="3"; H5; and so on)`
notice the Hs changing, which messes up the function.

**Is there a way to get to my desired outcome without batch editing the function everytime myself?**

Comment: Do you know how to use the $ sign to lock column and row?

Comment: If you reference them like `$H$2` etc (note the `$`) this will lock the range to not change when copied down ( or aside)